# How to change index.html metadata dynamically at routing time in Angular 6?

Tags: angular6, metadata

I am trying to replace the metadata values dynamically at routing time, but it's not working because Facebook is fetching data before routing happening.

Is there an approach I could try to get it working?

Comment: You should duck: server-side rendering (SSR). It is a common problem with common solutions.